# Parent child group giving blank rows when row is getting hide based exp - SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am using LIST control and inside it a tablix then In tablix I have taken another tablix inside it that is basically for group by sub account type for particular section of report.
[image]
There is basically parent child group relation.

report Design like below -

LIST( Gorup on ACCOUNT TYPE)--> Normal tablix (tablix1) --> taken another tablix (tablix2) inside cells of tablix1 and it group on subaccount type --> when I put hidden exp on a row of (tablix2) then it is hiding the rows based on criteria but it is giving blank rows.

I want to remove/shrink blank rows from output of report. When I put hidden rows by exp on child group then it giving extra blank rows.

I also set ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true in report properties but it also not worked.
Please advice on this issue.

Comment: Why are you nesting the tablixes? I guess that the blank row you see isn't a row of tablix2 but a row of tablix1 instead.

Comment: Blank rows is coming in Tablix3. When there is one distinct group values is coming child group and hide condition match then it is giving hidden rows is coming as extra blank in report output in tablix3.

Comment: Was this meant as a reply to my comment?

Comment: yes Wolfgang !!

Comment: Ok, then… Please post your **COMPLETE** question. You did not mention a "Tablix3". Also, please add images of both design and the (unwanted) result with the blank row. Afterwards, if you want me to have a look, please answer my question about nesting the tablixes. Also: How/where did you specify the expression to hide the row?

Comment: @WolfgangKais Extra blank rows is coming in Tablix3 when row is getting hide based on exp. Design explanation - LIST CONTROL ( group by account type) --> taken Tablix1-->Inside tablix1's rows --> inserted tablix2 (there is only one cells which getting group by subaccountid) --> Inside Tablix2's cells inserted Tablix3 for the details rows - the details rows need to shown multiple time in report based of number of subaccountid values. I am putting hide expression on Tablix3's 2nd static rows --> when hide exp match then values is not showing in report but giving blank row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I don't seem to find anything to point on, because you seem to hide important details.

As you seem to target an Excel export, you probably don't need a list. If you don't need column groups in your report, start with a table.

- Specify all the fields that will appear in a details row, add columns if needed.
- Right-click the details group to add a parent group (by *subaccount type*) with header/footer if required. Specify the headings and totals in the group header/footer and add columns ("inside the group") if required.
- Right-click the *subaccount type* group to add a parent group (by *account type*) with header/footer if needed. Specify headings and totals in the group header/footer and add columns ("inside the group") if required.
- Set the "row visibility" for the details row as needed.

If the hidden rows still appear in the Excel export, I suggest to exclude them from the dataset by using the report parameters (as `@RptRunDate` and `@PlanYearExpDate`) in a WHERE clause of the query that is used to create the dataset.

Comment: I need list because requirement is to export 4 different report for each account type. I can not create parent group in list, it is already there. the report I am creating is kind of summary report and Tablix1 is static report but its rows cells are having multiple tablix like .. example - tablix2. tablix2 only has one datarow cells and it being used to group by subaccoundid then tablix3 (static) just some summary exp to show values in this report and it getting iterated for every subaccound id.if there is only one distinct values is coming in subaccount id then this issue is occurring.

Comment: If the reports for the 4 account types were different, you wouldn't be able to display them in a list. So why not add a parent group to Tablix1 (Account Type) and place that tablix directly in the report (removing the list)?